Get data in AWS S3 from Sharepoint using AWS AppFlow
I am trying to get data from Sharepoint to S3 using appflow and am able to build the flow.
The data is getting partitioned by the Execution ID. Searched the web and the AWS documentation which suggests that there is an option "Partitioned and aggregation" section where I can remove this partition. However, that option doesn't exist in the flow for me. I am currently using AWS Redshift serverless free tier.
So, Flow is working but unable to remove partitioned loading of data into S3.
Any suggestions to fix this is highly appreciable, thanks.
Checked AWS Documentation -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/latest/userguide/flows-partition.html
This option is not popping up for me: 

How is is this related to Sharepoint?  Did you fix the issue? Does the sharepoint has a rest api (http) to download data?

Nope the issue is still not resolved. I am able to connect Sharepoint api through AWS AppFlow to get data in S3. The problem is as below:
In every job run, the job saves like this -
{Execution ID} / {Folder name} / {Files}
Whereas I want to save like this -
{Folder name} / {Files}
As per AWS Documentation, this is doable by unchecking the partition option in the AppFlow however that option doesn't exist for me.

Where is supposed to exist the "remove partition option"? Share us a screenshots of your app flow config

If you check this AWS documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/latest/userguide/flows-partition.html
I am not able to see that option where I can check out the Execution ID..
